# alias in .cshrc to kill processes

Tags: linux, awk, alias, csh

I have a bunch of `'abcd'` processes that I want to kill and restart frequently. I do this to kill them

```
kill -9 `ps -ef | grep abcd | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
```

Because I do it so frequently, I want to create an alias in the .cshrc file.

```
alias killabcd 'kill -9 `ps -ef | grep abcd | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`'
```

But it seems like $2 of awk is getting expanded and I get this error when I open a terminal

```
Missing }.
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I create an alias for this in my cshrc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply with **`pkill`** command:

```
alias killabcd 'pkill abcd'
```

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind! I figured it out!

This is one of the ways to do it:

```
alias killabcd 'kill -9 `ps -ef | grep abcd | grep -v grep | awk \{print\ \$2\}`'
```